# number of days passed on quarter for a given day

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I work at a non profit where we need to track the length of stay according normal american quarters (Jan, April, July, October). We also need to do this for all data from past tenants.

**We have:**

-one column for a move-in date.

-One column for a move-out date.

**We want:**

-One column to tell us how many quarters they have lived here to date, not just what quarter the move-in date falls in.

-One column to tell us how many days they have lived here in total (we have a simple date-minus-date formula here).

-One column to tell me how many days they have have been here in this quarter.

(IMPORTANT: **The most important formula that I need is one that can take a move-in date and tell me how many days someone has lived here in that quarter when that quarter is finished, and similarly a formula that can do the same for a move-out date**)

Thank you all so much,

B

Comment: "Stackoverflow is not a programming service."

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site is for programmers helping programmers, not someone simply designing something for you. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have downloaded Tableau and am trying my hand at it. I've been parsing date if, date add, and date trunc, formulas that I'm coming across to see if I can make something work. I've put in a bunch of hours and am going to go buy a book on Excel formulas this week.  I've been putting in a lot of hours and just thought I might ask a community of people knowledgeable at this point. This is really not designing something for me. It for a small nonprofit that finds affordable housing for young adults who have aged out foster care. We are underfunded and just trying to make things work.

Comment: Would you be able to direct me to a forum where these questions are welcomed? Thanks for your time and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve to find a -somehow- generic formula solution for this one. I tried to test all possible scenarios, please let me know if I've missed any.

First we need some helper cells in order to get our formula understand what is the starting day for quarters. 1st row is entered manually for this purpose.

[image: Excel Screenshot]

At this point the formula to calculate how many days there are between Move-in & Move-out dates which are within a quarter is as follows. This is for E3, s/b copied to right and down:

```
=IF(EDATE(E$1,3)-1-E$1-IF($B3>EDATE(E$1,3)-1,0,EDATE(E$1,3)-1-$B3)-IF($A3-E$1<0,0,$A3-E$1)<0,0,EDATE(E$1,3)-1-E$1-IF($B3>EDATE(E$1,3)-1,0,EDATE(E$1,3)-1-$B3)-IF($A3-E$1<0,0,$A3-E$1)+1)
```

Now the rest is easy. Formula for D3 is as follows (or instead you may sum up the quarters):

```
=B3-A3+1
```

And finally, the count of the active quarters in C3 is:

```
=COUNTIF(E3:I3, ">0")
```

I wish I had time to explain the formula entirely but I think you may get it if you spend some time on it; there is just some addition/subtraction math behind.